Azure Front Door - How do I use regular expression in "Patterns to match"
I am trying a Azure Front Door route configuration  based on the below path in the URL and I am not able to use it directly as shown. looks like "?" is causing this error and if I remove ?, it being allowed. Its not allowing /login* too. Any pointers on how do I configure this.
/login?RelayState=%2Ftest

Tried regular expressions instead of ? but no luck

It is not possible in front door

Azure Front Door's "Patterns to match" field does not support full regular expressions and has strict rules on how patterns should be defined. This is why you are encountering errors when trying to use special characters like "?" or patterns such as /login?RelayState=%2Ftest.
As an alternative, you can try using:
AFD Rules Engine : Configure Azure Front Door rules match conditions | Microsoft Learn

Request path as condition
Route configuration override as Action

also checkout - How requests get matched to a route configuration - Azure Front Door | Microsoft Learn
This article describes how Azure Front Door matches incoming requests to a route configuration.
